# NullPointerException Issue

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to implement the following code and I am running into an issue with static referencing to a non-static method.

```
public class App {
  public static void main (String args[]) { 
    int result = factorial(5);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  private int factorial(int value) {

    if (value == 0) 
      return 1;
    int sum = value * factorial(value-1);
    return sum;

  } 
}
```

Running the above code, I get the error below:

```
Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method factorial() from the type App
```

If I remove the static keyword from the main method, I get a NullPointerException error stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at 
edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I'm not quite sure how to work around this problem, any help is appreciated thanks.

Edit: I forgot to include a parameter when calling the factorial method, it is fixed now, sorry.

Comment: Change `private int factorial()` to `private static int factorial()`

Comment: Shouldn't you call `factorial` with a parameter? You are calling it with `factorial()`.

Comment: Pass a parameter to the `factorial(int)` method. Either make it a static or call it by an instance of the current class `App` like `new App().factorial(100);`.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an existing `static main` method. It gets looked for and when you can't find it that's the error you are receiving.

You can fix your particular problem by making `factorial` a static method.

Comment: If I make the factorial method static, I still get the same run-time error.

Comment: @AbdullaKubba it needs to be called with an int parameter

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `factorial` - an instance member form a static method `main` that is why the error is coming. You can declare `factorial` as a static method to resolve this.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int result = factorial(5); // you need to pass a int value here
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int factorial(int value) {
        if (value == 0)
            return 1;
        return value * factorial(value - 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: The factorial method is expecting an int value to be parsed through, yet with your solution it is not getting anything. Perhaps you made a typo? Sorry

Comment: Yes I forgot to pass a parameter, thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed my original post. Even with your solution, I still get the same runtime error unforunately.

Comment: @AbdullaKubba which is the java version used? are you using any IDE for development

Comment: @AbdullaKubba you should not remove `static` from the `main` method

Answer (score 1):

To call a non-static method from a static method create an object of class containing the non-static method. By definition, a non-static method can only be called on the object of some class, whereas a static method can be called on the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access normal methods inside a static mehod .

Instance methods are associated with a particular instance of the type, where as static methods are associated with the overall type

Try

```
 private static int factorial(int value) {
```

### -----------

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As error clearly says, you cannot access non-static methods inside a static methods, in-order to make this code work change your `factorial` definition as below:

```
private static int factorial(int value) {
  //remaining code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this. My compiler was unhappy with this code until I changed the call to `factorial` so it matched the function definition:

```
int result = factorial(23);
```

instead of

```
int result = factorial();
```

Changing the function declaration of `factorial` to `static` was also needed:

```
private int factorial(int value) {
```

But it needed both these things to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way if you don't want your method to be a `static` one, or you want to call it from another class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        new App();
    }

    private int factorial(int value) {
        if (value == 0) 
            return 1;
        int sum = value * factorial(value-1);
        return sum;
    }

    public App(){
        int result = factorial(6);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

you method `factorial(int value)` is parameterised so you should pass `int` value to it like I have passed in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will  working fine just add the `static` keyword.

```
private static int factorial(int value) {
```